# Creating a unique Primary Key for use in AWS DynamoDB

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I want to use an 8 char alphanumeric objectId (like Parse did) as my primary key.  Does AWS DynamoDB have a function to create this or do I need to create it somehow in my iOS app and submit it up to the DB?

Learning how DynamoDB works as I came from RDB background.

Also is it better to have one big table like say if I had Users and Photos, do I put that in the same table as Users take Photos? Or is there a way to link somehow?

Comment: Isn't the more table you use, the more the cost you need to pay in DynamoDB?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it doesn't. 
DynamoDB has very few features. You have to cook up something yourself. 
[Read](http://dynamodb-mapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/model.html#using-auto-incrementing-index) to get an idea of how to build a auto incrementing system for DynamoDB records.

Comment: If I have a Users table too, do I make it hold everything or break it apart into Users and Photos with Photo including the userId?

Comment: This is purely a design decision. I usually de-normalize the data and store related attributes/entitites together. But with the limited features that DynamoDB offers, if you need to search by photos for some reason, then you need to create a separate table and index for photos. Have a read of this also to get more background into nosql modeling (https://highlyscalable.wordpress.com/2012/03/01/nosql-data-modeling-techniques/)

Comment: I definitely prefer the denormalized way but will have to read on how it affects the queries in DynamoDB.

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB recommends the use of [single table design](https://www.alexdebrie.com/posts/dynamodb-single-table/). The purpose of this is to eliminate `join`s which are expensive so it can just focus on fetching the data. There are drawbacks to this and it's confusing as hell coming from a RDBMS foundation but you do get great response times when you're dealing with a mammoth dataset.

You could create a table of users and photos but you would have to create the `join` functionality manually. An example of properly leveraging DynamoDB, is to a single table of user photos (assuming that's your only data) where the primary key is a composite of a user ID and a photo URL.